# How is the credited director for any one Game of Thrones episode decided?

Tags: game-of-thrones, credits

My research for this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/what-is-the-reason-for-the-many-directors-used-in-the-game-of-thrones-series) revealed that due to extensive location shooting and use of wide-ranging intertwining storylines, Game of Thrones shoots with up to [three different units](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/2012/10/17/good-things-come-in-threes.html) [concurrently](http://www.atlasofwonders.com/2013/03/game-of-thrones-film-locations.html) in varying locations. These units have different directing teams, but footage from each is used in a released episode. How is the credited director decided?

Comment: Second and third unit directing is common, especially in films. Whatever director covers the "main" footage (most prominently featured story-line) is the director. (Not 100% on this for Game of Thrones, as I don't watch. Thus a comment instead of answer.)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. Most second-unit filming is used for location shots, special effects, sub-plots, etc. Game of Thrones 3-unit filming covers storylines that are equally important, which is why I brought it up as a special case.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_unit

Comment: I understand 2nd Unit, but wasn't sure if the episodes had a main plot and then slightly less relevant (for *that* episode) subplots. I saw the first two episodes and the Red Wedding and that's it. Thus it's not a proper answer. **It's almost like I got a mini Q&A inside THIS Q&A! It's a 2-for!** ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand all the filming units are under the supervision of one single director (the one who is credited) who is shooting with the main unit that shoots the Westeros segments which constitute the bulk of the series. The main unit started off shooting in Northern Ireland, moved to Malta, and more recently are shooting in Croatia. The other units (mostly shooting in Morocco and Iceland) have a bit of autonomy for convenience sake, but are still under the supervision of the main unit director(s).

Comment: I would imagine also that the more independent directors such as those in Iceland follow their storyline through a couple of episodes. So their theme/understanding/characterisations are carried through that thread of the overall story.

Comment: The name of the constituent country in the UK is *Northern Ireland*.

Comment: @TRiG - Fixing it now